# Pagerduty API integration and auto-resolution

Tags: monitoring, pagerduty

It is possible to implement auto-resolution with Pagerduty API integration. When a monitoring system detects an issue based on some metric and a threshold, it would create a Pagerduty incident through the API integration. Later, if the metric falls below the threshold, it could automatically resolve the incident, in case it is still open.

This feature could be very useful for several reasons:

#### Cases where a large number of incidents get triggered due to a common root cause

In this case, the on call person is spared from having to ack/resolve so many incidents and instead focus on troubleshooting and fixing the problem.

#### Auto-resolution would capture the incident duration more accurately

Humans are not good in doing things on a timely basis. If we are computing MTTR based on manual resolution of incidents, it may lead to inaccurate measurements.

Has anyone implemented auto-resolution with Pagerduty? If so, would you be able to talk about the pros and cons?

Comment: Related: [Advantages of API versus Email Integration](https://community.pagerduty.com/forum/t/advantages-of-api-versus-email-integration/1439).

Answer (score 2):

PD has a lot of native integrations that can do auto-resolve but for those that don't you can use the API and/or rulesets to do that.

Here is a link to the ruleset documentation: https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/rulesets

And here is documentation on the incident resolution API:
[https://developer.pagerduty.com/api-reference/reference/REST/openapiv3.json/paths/~1incidents~1%7Bid%7D/put](https://developer.pagerduty.com/api-reference/reference/REST/openapiv3.json/paths/%7E1incidents%7E1%7Bid%7D/put)

In the API call you would pass the following json body to resolve it:
{
"incident": {
"type": "incident_reference",
"status": "resolved"
}
}